# Solving the differential equation $m\dot{v}=-cv^2-f_{fr}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

$$m\dot{v}=-cv^2-f_{fr}$$

In a textbook that I am reading, I am tasked to solve the above differential equation, providing $t$ as an explicit function of $v$.

Here is my attempt at solving this differential equation:
$m\dot{v}=-cv^2-f_{fr}$
$\implies \frac{m\dot{v}}{-cv^2-f_{fr}} = 1$
$\implies -m \int_{v_0}^{v} \frac{1}{cv^2+f_{fr}} dv = t$
$\implies t = \frac{-m}{f_{fr}} \int_{v_0}^{v} \frac{1}{1+\frac{c}{f_{fr}}v^2} dv$
$\implies t = \frac{-m}{\sqrt{cf_{fr}}} \arctan \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}}v \right) _{v_0}^v$
$\implies t = \frac{m}{\sqrt{cf_{fr}}} \arctan \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}}(v_0-v) \right)$

However, the answer provided is
$t = \frac{m}{\sqrt{cf_{fr}}}
\left(
    \arctan \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}} v_0 - \arctan \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}} v
\right)$. To my knowledge, these two answers are not equivalent. Is there any error in my working that led to a different answer?

Comment: You were good up until the very end. $\arctan$ is not a linear function so you cannot write definite integral evaluation step the way you did.

Comment: You could also explore the second derivative of $z=e^{cx/m}$ with $\dot x=v$. Also take care that the air friction term always slows down, which is the case here as long as $v\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I skipped too many steps.
$\implies t = \frac{-m}{\sqrt{cf_{fr}}} \arctan \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}}v \right) _{v_0}^v$
should be written as
$\implies t = \frac{-m}{\sqrt{cf_{fr}}} \left[ \arctan \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{f_{fr}}}v \right) \right]_{v_0}^v$
so that the definite integral can be evaluated without mistakes